# How can I convert an array with two sets of brackets to have only one set of brackets?

Tags: typescript

how can I convert  `[[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]]` to

`[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]`?

I pushed an array to another, now I want to remove outer brackets from `ii` .

I'm looking for a method.

```
let ii :any[]=[];
const i =  ' '.repeat(10) ;
const d =  i.split('')   ; 
const aa=ii.push(d);
console.log(ii,ii.length);
console.log(d,d.length );
```

Comment: Why are you pushing the inner array into the outer array if you don't want the outer array at all?

Comment: Have you tried `const a = aa[0]` ?

Comment: @Orace Ruby is not TypeScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern javascript enviroments support [the `flat()` method.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

```js
const flatData = [["a", "b", ["c", "d"]]].flat(2)
console.log(flatData)
// ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

The number you can optionally pass to `flat()` is the number of levels to flatten.